# How to store messages with multiple recipients in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I am coding my first web app and I use Postgres to store data.

I would like to implement the following feature: messages with multiple recipients. Optimally, it would great to have threading support as well. Basically, I want something like email with threads, but within my own app.

I am new to RDBMS, so I haven't figured the best way to organize the tables. How do I store such many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

- a table for the users of your app, with the usual columns (unique `id`, `name`, etc.),
- a table for messages, with also a unique `id`, and a column to indicate which message it replies to; this will let you build threading
- a third table which constitutes the many to many relationship, with a foreign key on the user table and a foreign key on the message table,

Getting all the recipients for a given message, or all the messages for a given recipient is just doing a couple of inner joins between all three tables and the proper where clause.

For threading, you will need a recursive common table expression, which let you follow up the links between rows in the message table.

Something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE threads AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, id AS root_id, body
    FROM messages
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT msg.id AS id , msg.parent_id AS parent_id, msgp.root_id AS root_id, msg.body AS body
    FROM messages AS msg
    INNER JOIN threads AS msgp
    ON (msg.parent_id = msgp.id)
)
SELECT *
FROM threads
WHERE root_id = :root;
```

Where the column `root_id` contains the row id at the origin of the thread of the current row, will let you select a single thread whose `root_id` is set by the parameter `:root`.

With multiple recipients, you need to do the inner joins on `threads`:

```
WITH ...
)
SELECT *
FROM threads
INNER JOIN threads_users tu
ON threads.id = tu.msg_id
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = tu.user_id
WHERE root_id=:root
```

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but leads in the wrong direction in my opinion. Your query is loading all messages, so a `select * from messages` would do the same, or am I wrong? You also assume, that he wants to load whole subtrees. If that's true, he will probably load whole threads, in which case a thread_id would be much more efficient. As I wrote in my answer: Trees in RDBMs are a tricky topic. You should go for the most simple solution and then - if needed - pick some implementation which fits your needs.

Comment: @Achim, Thank you for your input! It is true that the query result is very simplistic, I was merely demonstrating the mechanism used to query threads within a table embedding a tree structure. I'll try to update my answer with a better, more accurate example using the same underlying principle.

Answer (score 3):

There are whole books about how to map data structures to the relational model, so my answer has to be just a first very simple hint. Let's call it a "default case":

You usually would have one table for your messages (one row = one message) and one for the recipients (one row = one recipient). Both must have some unique key, which is usually a column called id having unique integer numbers.

You connect (or relate ;-)) those two tables with a third one. This one has just two columns, holding the id of the message and the id of the recipient. So there is exactly one row for each message-recipient relation. That's a so called m:n relation.

The threading of messages is a 1:m relation. One message can have multiple children, but each message can have only one parent. Therefor you don't need the "middle table" from the message-recipient table. You can store the id of the parent message in the messages table.

Just to make you aware of that: RDBMS are not really made for this kind of tree like structures as your message threads. As you just get started, it might be a frustrating first example. And even if it works it will be slow for a non trivial amount of data. There are solutions to get trees fast in SQL, but you have to learn the basics first.